# Modifying photo's date stored inside the photo file from files name?

Tags: scripts, media, metadata, photo, exif

I am using Google's PhotScan app to scan all my old photos that are taken before the digital cameras age, and I am saving these photos using the date of the photo (example: 19821011_trip.jpg, yyyymmdd_trip.jpg).

But this method saves the current date of taking the photo using the app in the photo's properties, so what I was trying to write is a script that will take the date information from the photo's filename and correct the date that is stored in the photo's file properties.

Looking forward to get your help.

Comment: Please show an example of the original name and the new name so we can determine if the new files can be identified from the old name so renaming can be possible!

Answer (score 4):

#### `exiftool` to the rescue

I assume you want to change the *EXIF data* of your scanned images according to the timestamp from the image's filename (not from the time the file was created like e.g. `ls -l` shows).

Fortunately, there is a handy tool for this called [`exiftool`](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). If it is not yet installed, run

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

first. `exiftool` is in the standard repositories. It can show and manipulate both filenames and EXIF data. For example, it is possible to move files around according to the EXIF attribute *CreateDate* and move files to subdirectories like

```
2018
    Jan
       img0001.jpg
       img0002.jpg
    Feb
       img0003.jpg
       img0004.jpg
```

and so on. But that's another story and you want it just the other way round.

Let's take your `19821011_trip.jpg` as an example and set all three attributes *DateTimeOriginal*, *CreateDate*, and *ModifyDate* to `Oct 11, 1982`. `exiftool` has a parameter to parse the filename for something that looks like a date and timestamp and then set all these dates at once to that value. Unfortunately the filename must contain a timestamp (HHMMSS) for this to work, like so:

```
exiftool "-alldates<filename" 19821011_130000_trip.jpg
```

This would set the three date attributes mentioned above to `Oct 11, 1982, 01:00:00 PM`. Since your filename does *not* contain such an HHMMSS part, we must change the parameter a bit:

```
exiftool '-alldates<${filename;$_=substr($_,0,8)} 13:00:00' 19821011_trip.jpg
```

This will pick the first 8 characters from the filename, append `13:00:00` and finally parse that string (`19821011 13:00:00`) to build a proper date for all three attributes. `exiftool` is pretty good at parsing timestamps, but it *needs* at least an HHMM part after the date.

You can also run `exiftool` on a whole directory:

```
exiftool '-alldates<${filename;$_=substr($_,0,8)} 13:00:00' .
```

It will then process all images it finds. No worries, it makes backups of all modified files.

#### Summary:

```
me@ubuntu:~> exiftool -alldates 19821011_trip.jpg
(no output)

me@ubuntu:~> exiftool '-alldates<${filename;$_=substr($_,0,8)} 13:00:00' 19821011_trip.jpg 
    1 image files updated

me@ubuntu:~> exiftool -alldates 19821011_trip.jpg 
Date/Time Original              : 1982:10:11 13:00:00
Create Date                     : 1982:10:11 13:00:00
Modify Date                     : 1982:10:11 13:00:00
```

Comment: The use of the substr to pull the numbers is unnecessary.  See [Exiftool FAQ 5](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q5), paragraph 3.  All you need to do in this case is `exiftool '-alldates<$Filename 13:00:00' DIR`  If there are other numbers that aren't part of the date/time, then you would have to parse in some way.

Comment: @StarGeek That is even better and it works for the filename `19821011_trip.jpg`. I'll add that information to the answer as soon as I have some spare time. But feel invited to update my post. However, I didn't manage to fetch that information from the FAQ. :-( Maybe, because I don't know what `XMP` is.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't counting the examples as paragraphs.  Skip to the part that starts "Having said this, ExifTool is very flexible about the actual format of input date/time values when writing"  tl;dr is that exiftool will ignore the non-numeric characters and treat the numbers as YYYYMMDD HHmmSS.

Comment: It's complicated. I tried `exiftool '-alldates<filename' 19821011_trip.jpg` first and that complained about invalid date/time format. `exiftool '-alldates<filename' 19821011_130000_trip.jpg` worked but that's not the actual filename, and I added that substr stuff. But your suggestion `exiftool '-alldates<$Filename 13:00' 19821011_trip.jpg` works and is easier to read and write. Thank you again.

Comment: The substring (or regex substitution) is good to remember in case there is any additional non-time based numbers, such as a file increment e.g `19821011_trip_001.jpg`, `19821011_trip_002.jpg`, etc.  In those cases, you do need do something extra to get only the numbers you need.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks for your answer, but I need to run it on the whole directory you suggested: ///exiftool '-alldates<${filename;$_=substr($_,0,8)} 13:00:00'/// but it returns: error No file specified

Comment: There is a dot after my command (indicating the current directory). Or do `command *.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do that with `touch` and a loop like

```bsh
for i in *.jpg; do
  touch -d"${i%_trip.jpg}" "$i"
done
```

but that’s not very exact, as your file names only contain the date without any time information, the file’s time will thus be set to 00:00:00.000000000. Stay with me for a better way.

Every regular photo has an Exif header which contains the correct time stamp of when the photo was taken, provided the date and time settings of the camera were correct. I always prefer using this, it’s failproof and easy with `jhead` from the package `jhead`, see [`man jhead`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/jhead.1.html) for details. Some useful options are:

```
-ft    Sets the file's system time stamp to what is stored in the Exif header.    
-n[format_string]
       This option causes files to be renamed and/ or mmoved using the date information from the Exif header "DateTimeOriginal" field.  If the file is not an Exif file, or the DateTimeOriginal
       does not contain a valid value, the file date is used.  If the new name contains a '/', this will be interpreted as a new path, and the file will be moved accordingly.
```

A command to rename all `jpg` files in the current directory according to their Exif header time stamp and changing the file's system time stamp could be:

```bsh
jhead -ft -n'%Y%m%d_trip' *.jpg
```

`jhead` is wise enough not to overwrite your files if the filename already exists:

> If the target name already exists, the name will be appended with "a",
>   "b", "c", etc, unless the name ends with a letter, in which case it
>   will be appended with "0", "1", "2", etc.

If your files don’t have an Exif header the following options may be of help:

```
-mkexif
       Creates  minimal exif header. Exif header contains date/time, and empty thumbnail fields only. Date/time set to file time by default. Use with -rgt option if you want the exif header to
       contain a thumbnail. Note that exif header creation is very limited at this time, and no other fields can be added to the exif header this way.
-dsft  Sets the Exif timestamp to the file's timestamp. Requires an Exif header to pre-exist. Use -mkexif option to create one if needed.
```

Comment: To my understanding the OP just wants it the other way round: set the Exif data to the timestamp from the filename. Maybe `exiftool` can do that.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks, I didn’t realize that, see my update.

Comment: @dessert thanks for your reply, I have tried:  // for i in *.jpg; do
  touch -d"${i%_trip.jpg}" "$i"
done//   but point the "_trip is not constant part in all file names, sometimes _numbers sometime _letters so I was trying to modify your for loop but I did not find a way.  What is constant in filename is that it always start with 8 characters that presents the date YYYYMMDD.